# Android remainder app using job scheduler

Tags: java, android, android-alarms, android-jobscheduler

I am making remainder app. After reading documentation I came to know that I should use Job Scheduler instead of Alarm Manager. I am using job scheduler recursively but after 10... 15 hours this recursion stops and my alarm is missed. Can someone please help me about the best way to implement remainder app. I am sharing my Job Scheduler code below

Here is Job Scheduler starting function

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(10 * 60 * 1000); // wait at least 10 mins
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(60 * 1000); // maximum delay 1 min
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());

    }
```

below is JobService

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(service);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "scheduled called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

below is service declaration in manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".TestJobService"
    android:label="Word service"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Use Work Manager its easy and `The WorkManager API is a suitable and recommended replacement for all previous Android background scheduling APIs, including FirebaseJobDispatcher, GcmNetworkManager, and Job Scheduler.` [See more](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Answer (score 0):

The job scheduler does not work properly anymore. You should use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#groovy). But If you still want to get an exact reminder you should use Alarm Manager with full-screen intent and tell users to disable battery saving for the app. [Full-screen intent notification](https://medium.com/android-news/full-screen-intent-notifications-android-85ea2f5b5dc1)